# Create a table containing PK and FK

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to explain what this table does, but unable to see what is happening here.  Any suggestion?

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    MGID INT REFERENCES EMP (ID),
    NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

It's creating a table called `EMP` which describes employees. Each employee is identified by a surrogate `ID` number, has a `NAME` attribute, and a relationship with a manager identified by `MGID`.

Answer (score 1):

This code creates a table that's called `EMP`, with a primary key column called `ID` of type `int`, a foreigen key referencing that column called `MGID`, and a string column called `NAME`.

Using a foriegn key to the same table enables you to create parent/child relationship for rows in that table. 
For instance, if you have an employee that's called `Raza`, and his manager is calld `Far`, You will have a row for the manager and a row for `Raza` and the value of `MGID` in that row would point to the `ID` of `Far`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have some basic knowledge of DBMS, I think you stuck with 'REFERENCES' keyword.
It creates a Parent/Child relationship between ID and MGID.
As you know, the table is for Employee(as the name suggested 'Emp'), Manager is also an employee.
So,before referencing to any employee as a manager it must have entry in table as employee. To perform this kind of validations, 'REFERENCES' keyword can be used.

For example,

```
                    ID  MGID  NAME
                     1  null   a
                     2   1     b
                     3   1     c
```

Above data is valid but,

```
                     ID  MGID  NAME
                     1   null   a
                     2    3     b
                     3    1     c
```

Above data will violate the referential integrity constraints as any employee with ID 3 is not existed yet.

Hope it helps.